# Подключение к MySQL вопрос на тему порта

Tags: mysql, исключения, jdbc

Добрый день!
Возникла необходимость отловить неправильно введённые url\port\login\password для подключения к БД и выводить соответствующие сообщения об ошибках. 
Всё кроме порта я отлавливаю с помощью нужных `exception`, но с портом возникла беда: для него `exception` идентичен тому же, что выскакивает при неправильно введённом url.
Собственно сам вопрос:
Можно ли как-то отдельно вычленить неправильно введённый порт для подключения к БД?

Comment: нет, потому что ваш клиент не может подключиться к паре хост:порт, и не может сказать, указан ли только неправильный порт, только неправильный хост, или и то, и то.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Для установки соединения нужен правильный **ip и порт**. Если один из них неверен, то нельзя сказать, из-за чего именно не вышло подключиться к базе. Невозможно различить следующие возможные ошибки (при любой из них просто не удастся соединиться с сервером на уровне TCP/IP):

1. Это не тот сервер (mysql на другом сервере на том же порту).
2. Это правильный сервер, но не тот порт (mysql на другом порту).
3. Это правильный сервер и порт, но mysql не запущен (порт никто не слушает).
4. Это правильный сервер и порт, но он закрыт фаерволом.